# Can you have multiple active route tables in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-peering

I was trying to set up VPC peering in AWS.  I got most of it working but the network connectivity didn't work.  I narrowed down the difference to the routes.

In my previous working system I had the VPC peering route in the main routing table, but when I terraformed a new system I tried to create a separate routing table with the VPC peering route but that didn't work.

I had to manually go to AWS console to add the route on the main route table for the communications to work.

Answer (score 2):

Main route table controls the routing for all subnets that are **not explicitly associated** with any other route table

If your subnet is associated with a custom route table, put the peering route in the associated route table

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html